# Handling null values from a datareader to a subroutine

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm copying records retrieved by a datareader (both strings and dates) and inserting them into a database. I am passing these values from the datareader to a subroutine named InsertNewHearings(). My problem is that values retrieved by the dr are often NULL and cause an error "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Date' is not valid"

```
Using con
  con.Open()
  dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
  While dr.Read()
     Dim LastUserID As String = lblLastUserID.Text
     UserID = GetRandomUser(LastUserID)
     Dim strAssigned_Date As Date = DateTime.Now()
     Dim strUpload_Date As Date = DateTime.Now()
     InsertNewHearings(dr("Borrower_Number"), 
     dr("Review_Doc_Date"), dr("Review_Type"), dr("PCAID"), 
     dr("Day65_Notice_Date"), dr("Hearing_Image_Date"), 
     dr("Additional_Docs_Date"), dr("Request_Postmark_Date"), 
     dr("Timeliness_Hearing_Request"), strUpload_Date, UserID, 
     strAssigned_Date)
   End While
  End Using

Sub InsertNewHearings(ByVal Borrower_Number As String, ByVal 
Review_Doc_Date As Date, ByVal Review_Type As String, ByVal PCAID As 
String, ByVal Day65_Notice_Date As Date, _
ByVal Hearing_Image_Date As Date, Additional_Docs_Date As Date, 
Request_Postmark_Date As Date, ByVal Timeliness_Hearing_Request As String, 
strUpload_Date As Date, UserID As String, strAssigned_Date As Date)
 'Inserts record into database
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `InsertNewHearings` signature to make params `Nullable`/`Nothing` that *could be*. So for example `Review_Doc_Date?, Day65_Notice_Date?` etc... If you don't change the signature to accept nullable params then you need to check every one of them first and then include a default value.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that above will only work if targeting vb.net >= 10, otherwise it would look something like `ByVal 
Review_Doc_Date As Nullable(Of Date)`.

Comment: When I use ByVal Day65_Notice_Date As Nullable(Of Date) I get "Specified cast is not valid"

Comment: And if you use the `?` what happens? Or changing them to `ByVal Review_Doc_Date As Nullable(Of DateTime)`

Comment: If I use ByVal Day65_Notice_Date? As Date, I get the same error.

Comment: Please [see](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l1CHAP) this, works just fine. But I see you are getting `DBNull` which isn't the same as `Nothing`/`null`, try wrapping the `dr` records. For example: `If(IsDbNull(dr("Borrower_Number"), New Date(), Nothing)`

Comment: Sorry, this `If(IsDbNull(dr("Borrower_Number"), New Date(), dr("Borrower_Number"))`. Basically checking for `DBNull`, if so we create a new date (your choice) or we pass the value... What you may need to do is create an extension you can just call to verify it and return a good date back or return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB.NET dates are a bit funky when handling a NULL date from a DB. First, to handle reading a date with a NULL value from the database into your VB.NET Date variable:

```
Dim myDate As Date = If(dr("MyDate") Is DBNull.Value, Nothing, dr("MyDate"))
```

Note that setting a Date type to Nothing gives it a value of #12:00:00# (the minimum value for a Date data type), and not Nothing as in a null object. Which means that you check a date for Nothing to send a NULL to the database like this:

```
cmd.Parameters("@MyDate").Value = If(.myDate = Nothing, DBNull.Value, .myDate)
```

Note that we *don't* use `If(.myDate Is Nothing,...`